# "google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined with Protobuf v2

Tags: protocol-buffers

I'm trying to use timestamps in my v2 `.proto` files.

I installed Protobuf v2.6.1 from source onto my Mac OS and followed the installation instructions in the README (e.g. `./configure`, `make`, `make check`, ...).

It seems that `protoc` is installed correctly as on my macOS machine I'm getting

```sh
$ protoc --version                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
libprotoc 2.6.1
```

However, when adding simple `.proto` files like

```
syntax = "proto2";

import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto";

message MyMessage {
  optional google.protobuf.Timestamp start_date = 1;
```

I'm getting

```
Import "google/protobuf/timestamp.proto" was not found or had errors.
"google.protobuf.Timestamp" is not defined.
```

What else am I supposed to do? I don't see an `include/` directory in my protobuf installation...